# How hard is it to get a license from WotC to publish a novel set in a D&D setting?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings, publishing, intellectual-property

Everybody is trying to get around writing their own stories without infringing any copyrights by WotC. That got me wondering...

How hard could it be to obtain a license to actually publish a book based on our campaign in the D&D Mystara setting (out of print)?

Back in the day not all published novels were all that great :-)

Comment: Some of the old-school writers are *still* in the industry, like R.A. Salvatore.  I bet someone could just ask him (or maybe they have already?).

Comment: @SouthpawHare I'm not sure they'd be useful to ask. They have established relationships and license/publishing agreements, and any “in the old days” info regarding how they connected with TSR won't be relevant to how to get a license from WotC today (or even last year or next, as business policies can change).

Comment: Asking how to get into the RPG business, even as a novelist, is not within the scope of this website.

Comment: Everybody? I’m not.